# Not able to locate Hydration Error: Initial UI does not match what was rendered

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I have been looking at this piece of code for over 2 days now, and i have not been able to locate my Hydration error. It is driving me crazy. Could some one maybe take a look at it for me? Are there any tips and tricks to spot these kind of errors more quickly, would love to know!

I'am using nextjs and using axios for the get resquest

These are the errors:
**Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.**

**Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.**

**react-dom.development.js?ac89:19849 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.**

````
  export async function getStaticProps() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('https://open.data.amsterdam.nl/Festivals.json')
      const events = res.data;
      return {
        props: {
          events: events.slice(0, 10)
        }
      } 
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
  


function EventsCards({events}) {

  return (
    <div>
      <a id="pressable-card max-w-md">
        <div id="featured-event-container" className="bg-black rounded-md bg-opacity-20 bg-blur-sm max-w-xs shadow-lg">
          <div id="event-banner">
            <img className="max-w-lg w-full h-full" src={events.media[0].url }/>
          </div>
          <div className="text-white pl-2">
            <h1 className="text-lg font-medium text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-400 to-pink-600">{events.title}</h1>
            <a className="text-sm uppercase">{events.title}</a>
            <a className="text-xs text-">Friday 20 Jan | 13:00 - 02:00</a>
          </div>
          <div className="py-2 px-2">
            <p className="text-slate-200 font-normal border-[1px] py-[2px] px-[4px] rounded-lg border-slate-400 w-8 text-[8px]">Techno</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  )
}
function Events({events}) {

  return (
      <div className="bg-gradient-to-t from-gray-500 to-gray-900 h-full bg-blur-sm pt-2">
        <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto">
          <div className="px-8 ">
            <div className="flex">
              <h1 className="text-white font-regular opacity-100 tracking-wider sm:text-xl md:text-2xl">Featured events in Amsterdam</h1>
              <div className="pl-2 my-auto">
                <img className="rounded-full w-8 h-8 md:w-6 md:h-6  border-gray-400" src="https://www.fotw.info/images/n/nl.gif"></img>
              </div>
            </div>
            <ul className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 pt-4 md:w-full">
              
              <div id="featured-wrapper" className="bg-black rounded-md bg-opacity-20 bg-blur-sm max-w-xs shadow-lg">
                <a id="pressable-card max-w-md">
                  <div id="featured-event-container">
                    <div id="event-banner">
                      <img className="max-w-lg max-h-lg w-full h-full" src='https://d1as2iufift1z3.cloudfront.net/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBaWpqIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--696c8f363a91d0501e8ae333fc9d42e5fd9c225f/ERT_HOLLAND_SIGNUP_banner%20(1).jpg?proxy=true'></img>
                    </div>
                    <div className="text-white pl-2">
                      <h1 className="text-lg font-medium text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-400 to-pink-600">El Row Town 2022 - Holland</h1>
                      <a className="text-sm uppercase">{events.title}</a>
                      <a className="text-xs text-">Friday 1 Jan | 11:00 - 04:00</a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="py-2 px-2">
                      <a className="text-slate-200 font-normal border-[1px] py-[2px] px-[4px] rounded-lg border-slate-400 w-8 text-[8px]">Techno</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div className="text-red-400"><h1>test</h1></div>
            </ul>
          </div>
          {/* Amsterdam Events */}
          <div className="flex justify-center py-8">
            <button className="text-[8px] uppercase font-medium rounded-md py-[8px] px-2 bg-white">see events in Amsterdam</button>
          </div>
          {/* All Events */}
          <div className="mx-auto max-w-6xl w-full">
            <h1 className="px-8 text-white font-regular tracking-wider text-xl md:text-2xl">Amsterdam</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="max-auto max-w-6xl">
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 pt-4 md:w-full w-full px-8 gap-4">
              {events.map((event) => (
                <EventsCards key={event.id} events={event} />
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

  )
}
export default Events;```
````

Comment: I had a similar problem and it turned out to be a browser extension (specifically in my case Grammarly).  Make sure to turn off your extensions that may add data properties into the page, thereby making the page different from what was rendered on the server.

Comment: if you check the console you'll see some `validateDOMNesting` errors about `<a>` cannot be descendant of `<a>`

Comment: I was just going to say that the other thing to check is invalid markup.  @mocherfaoui nailed it.

Comment: @mocherfaoui The only thing i get back is the following: Warning: data for page "/" is 270 kB which exceeds the threshold of 128 kB, this amount of data can reduce performance.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/large-page-data

Comment: @jme11 I have added the new error, it does not make me any wiser :3. Could the error be only in the file that i am reloading in the browser or could it be anywhere in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code that are causing issues:

1. Invalid markup (anchor tags inside other anchor tags, ul tags without li children).
2. You are passing the prop `events` to your `<EventCard />` component (it should have a name that is different from the events array retrieved server-side)
3. You are using a `event.id` for your key prop when none exists (it should be `event.trcid`).

Here's a basic working version of your components:

```
export default function Events({ events }) {
  return (
    <>
      {events.map((event) => (
        <EventsCards key={event.trcid} event={event} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

function EventsCards({ event }) {
  return <div>{event.title}</div>;
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(
      'https://open.data.amsterdam.nl/Festivals.json'
    );
    const events = res.data;
    return {
      props: {
        events,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

More often, it's best to start by getting the data on the page and then add in your additional content and styles.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment and great explanation, really helped me by you breaking it down. I had a lot of invalid markup (i did not realize this also could happen with anchor tags). You would recommend always by starting to get data on the page and style it afterwards, to avoid these kinds of errors?  Anyway, It works now! You're awesome mate, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you make some changes on the server side and save them before the Fast-Refresh completes hence causing a hydration error. You can manually reload the page after completing saving the changes or wait for Fast-Refresh to complete and then save your codes.